# How foreach array json in react native? When the display elements are not the same

Tags: json, loops, react-native, display

I have a array that contains 5 elements:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Title 1",
    "description": "descriptions"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Title 1",
    "description": "descriptions"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "title": "Title 1",
    "description": "descriptions"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "title": "Title 1",
    "description": "descriptions"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "title": "Title 1",
    "description": "descriptions"
  }
]
```

And I want them to show up as follows:

```
<Item>
  <Text style={styles.cardText}>Title 1</Text>
  <Text style={styles.cardText} numberOfLines={2}>Description 1</Text>
</Item>
<Grid>
  <Col>
    <Item>
      <Text style={styles.cardText}>Title 2</Text>
      <Text style={styles.cardText} numberOfLines={2}>Description 2</Text>
    </Item>
  </Col>
  <Col>
    <Item>
      <Text style={styles.cardText}>Title 3</Text>
      <Text style={styles.cardText} numberOfLines={2}>Description 3</Text>
    </Item>
  </Col>
</Grid>
<Grid>
  <Col>
    <Item>
      <Text style={styles.cardText}>Title 4</Text>
      <Text style={styles.cardText} numberOfLines={2}>Description 4</Text>
    </Item>
  </Col>
  <Col>
    <Item>
      <Text style={styles.cardText}>Title 5</Text>
      <Text style={styles.cardText} numberOfLines={2}>Description 5</Text>
    </Item>
  </Col>
</Grid>
```

How to display the above as in React Native?

I tried to use datas.map function but could not.
I tried to adding string but I thought that was not the solution.

Is there a solution for it?

Thank all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `chunk` the `array` into 2 parts for indexes other than 0.

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        data: [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "title": "Title 1",
                "description": "descriptions"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "title": "Title 1",
                "description": "descriptions"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "title": "Title 1",
                "description": "descriptions"
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "title": "Title 1",
                "description": "descriptions"
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "title": "Title 1",
                "description": "descriptions"
            }
        ],
        chunk: this.chunk
    }
}
```

Method for chunking `array`:

```
chunk(array, chunkSize) {
    return [].concat.apply([],
        array.map(function (elem, i) {
            return i % chunkSize ? [] : [array.slice(i, i + chunkSize)];
        })
    );
};
```

Rendering the items:

```
render() {
    let { data, chunk } = this.state;
    let dataForChunk = [...data];
    dataForChunk.splice(0, 1); //removes 1st index of array
    let chunkedArr = chunk(dataForChunk, 2);

    return (<View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <Item>
            <Text style={styles.cardText}> {data[0].title} </Text>
            <Text style={styles.cardText} numberOfLines={2} > {data[0].description} </Text>
        </Item>
        {chunkedArr.map((arr, index) => {
            return(
                <Grid>
                    {arr.map(item => {
                        return(
                            <Col>
                                <Item>
                                    <Text style={styles.cardText} >{item.id}</Text>
                                    <Text style={styles.cardText} numberOfLines={2}>{item.description}</Text>
                                </Item>
                            </Col>
                        );
                    })}
                </Grid>
            )
        })}
    </View>)
}
```

Comment: I am used it. Thank you very must!

Answer (score 0):

You can use FlatList instead.

Considering example

```
const row = [{key: 'a'}, {key: 'b'}]
```

FlatList Usage:

```
<FlatList
        data={row}
        renderItem={(item) => this._renderItem(item)}
        keyExtractor={extractKey}
        extraData={row}
        />
```

Rendering View inside function:

```
    _renderItem = ({item}) => {
    return <Text>{item.key}</Text>
   }
```